# MongoDB picking wrong index

Tags: mongodb

The following document is stored in a collection:

```
  "ldr": {
    "d": NumberInt(318),
    "w": NumberInt(46),
    "m": NumberInt(10),
    "pts": [
      {
        "lid": ObjectId("47cc67093475061e3d95369d"),
        "dPts": NumberLong(110),
        "wPts": NumberLong(110),
        "mPts": NumberLong(220),
        "aPts": NumberLong(3340)
      },
      {
        "lid": ObjectId("56316279be4f0eda62ebfee0"),
        "dPts": NumberInt(0),
        "wPts": NumberInt(0),
        "mPts": NumberInt(0),
        "aPts": NumberInt(0)
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have 4 indexes on a collection:

```
ldr.pts.lid_1_ldr.d_1_ldr.pts.dPts_-1
ldr.pts.lid_1_ldr.w_1_ldr.pts.wPts_-1
ldr.pts.lid_1_ldr.m_1_ldr.pts.mPts_-1
ldr.pts.lid_1_ldr.pts.aPts_-1
```

I use the following query:

```
db.my_collection.find({"ldr.pts.lid":ObjectId("47cc67093475061e3d95369d"), "ldr.w": NumberInt(46)},{"ldr":1}).sort({"ldr.pts.wPts":-1}).explain()
```

Note: I have run this query with the {ldr:1} left out with the same result.

I would expect the query above to use the following index:

```
ldr.pts.lid_1_ldr.w_1_ldr.pts.wPts_-1
```

However, this is the result of the explain:

```
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor ldr.pts.lid_1_ldr.d_1_ldr.pts.dPts_-1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 3,
        "nscannedObjects" : 4,
        "nscanned" : 4,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 16,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 16,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "ldr.pts.lid" : [
                        [
                                ObjectId("47cc67093475061e3d95369d"),
                                ObjectId("47cc67093475061e3d95369d")
                        ]
                ],
                "ldr.d" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ],
                "ldr.pts.dPts" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "Beast-PC:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

As you can see the first index is being picked.

I've tried using a hint and supplying the correct index but that still results in indexOnly being false and in scanAndOrder being true.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorting on a field within an array isn't likely to produce what you're expecting as your descending sort on `ldr.pts.wPts` will sort based on the max of all the `wPts` values from each document's `pts` array. That's at the root of why your query can't use an index for the sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How come it works perfectly for the dPts and aPts indexes? The only ones which appear to break are the week and month queries.

Comment: I've just ran some tests and you're right. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as the right one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting on a field within an array isn't likely to produce what you're expecting as your descending sort on `ldr.pts.wPts` will sort based on the *max* of all the `wPts` values from each document's `pts` array, rather than just the `wPts` value from the matching `pts` array element.

That's at the root of why your query can't use an index for the sorting.